# PKIX path failed en JAVA

Tags: java, ssl

estoy intentando leer un archivo desde una URI, y al ejecutar el programa me sale este error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at main.main(main.java:33)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
```

Investigando un poco he visto que es por los certificados del fichero "cacerts" dentro de la carpeta de instalación de Java, pero ya he importado los certificados de la página a la que quiero acceder y aun así me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Os dejo mi código de Java para la conexión por si el problema está en el código:

```
try {
             // Se abre la conexión
             URL url = new URL("https://contrataciondelestado.es/codice/cl/1.04/ServiceContractCode-1.04.gc");
             URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
             conexion.connect();
             
             // Lectura
             InputStream is = conexion.getInputStream();
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
             char[] buffer = new char[1000];
             int leido;
             while ((leido = br.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, leido));
             }
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Comment: No, el error está en que no encuentra los certificados. ¿Cómo has intentado importarlos?

Comment: Hola, he usado la herramienta de "keytool" desde el cmd, y también con un programa externo llamado "KeyStore Explorer"